# XSD to ensure element X is preceded by element Y

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm parsing a XML document and I want to make sure that every element `<element2>` is preceded by `<element1>` with the condition that there are no `<element3>` between them.

I know how to do this with XPath, but I can't figure a way to do this with XSD. Is there a way to do it? Am I using the right tool for the job or maybe I should "validate" it with a script?

Comment: If you know how to do it with XPath, then you know how to do it with assertions in XSD 1.1.  If you're limited to XSD 1.0, you're limited to arranging specific elements in sequence in set ways.

Comment: @kjhughes I gave it a try below with XSD 1.1, but the thing is I can't find 1.1 parsers for Python or PHP.  It seems that I'm stuck with 1.0 where this can't be solved. For purely didactic purposes, Do you think the code below can work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be usual to express this as a constraint on the content model of the element that is the parent of element1, element2, and element3.

Usually you would say what elements CAN appear between element1 and element3, but if it really is any element other that element3, then in XSD 1.1 you could define the content model as something like

```
<xs:element name="element1"/>
<xs:any not-QName="element3" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="element2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
<xs:element name="container">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"> 
      <xs:element name="element1"/>
      <xs:element name="element2"/>
      <xs:element name="element3"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:assert test="generate-id(element2/preceding-sibling::element1[1][following-sibling::element3[1]) 
                  eq generate-id(element2/following-sibling::element3[1])" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```